# Not working in PyMongo, but working in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

the below mongodb query runs fine on mongo shell

```
> db.mycoll.find( { $where: function() {return this.hash == '-8653408530678185564' || this._id == 'df8a2b91effa2143c0f7f663'} } )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5df8a2b91effa2143c0f7f66"), "row_data" : [ [ "198.0.0.0", "1576571739279", "-8653408530678185564", "1", "31", "31", "9167de:912349:", "9.9.0" ] ], "hash" : "-8653678185564" }
```

However, the same query, when run on pymongo is giving syntax error

```
  File "parse_v2.py", line 109
    coll.find({ '$where': function() {return this.hash == '-8653408530678185564' || this._id == 'df8a2b91effa2143c0f7f663'} } )
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Pymongo is not the same as the mongo shell. It's a software driver to the mongo back end. You can do most things in pymongo that you can do in the shell; but the approach, format or syntax may be different.

Try:

```
db.mycoll.find( {'$or': [{ hash: '-8653408530678185564'}, {'_id': 'df8a2b91effa2143c0f7f663'}] } )
```